# read byte stream to record

Tags: ada, endianness

So I am trying to read a file into a record, specified like so:

```
   type U32        is new Interfaces.Unsigned_32;
   type U16        is new Interfaces.Unsigned_16;
   type U8         is new Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
   type Rotation_t is range 0 .. 3             with Size => 2;
   type Tilenum_t  is new Interfaces.Unsigned_8;
   type Padding_t  is range 0 .. 7             with Size => 3;

   type Tile is record
      Tilenum :    Tilenum_t;
      XFlipped :   Boolean;
      YFlipped :   Boolean;
      Rotation :   Rotation_t;
      TriFlipped : Boolean;
      Padding :    Padding_t;
      Height :     U8;
   end record with Size => 24;

   for Tile use
   record
      --  first byte
      Tilenum    at 0 range 0 .. 7;       -- 1111 1111   0000 0000   0000 0000
      --  second byte
      XFlipped   at 0 range 8 .. 8;       -- 0000 0000   1000 0000   0000 0000
      YFlipped   at 0 range 9 .. 9;       -- 0000 0000   0100 0000   0000 0000
      Rotation   at 0 range 10 .. 11;     -- 0000 0000   0011 0000   0000 0000
      TriFlipped at 0 range 12 .. 12;     -- 0000 0000   0000 1000   0000 0000
      Padding    at 0 range 13 .. 15;     -- 0000 0000   0000 0111   0000 0000
      --  third byte
      Height     at 0 range 16 .. 23;     -- 0000 0000   0000 0000   1111 1111
   end record;
   for Tile'Bit_Order            use System.Low_Order_First;
   for Tile'Scalar_Storage_Order use System.Low_Order_First;
```

Note that information comes in by 3 bytes at a time.
On disk, I have:

```
# hexdump -C
# we are only interested in second line: first one is metadata
00000000  6d 61 70 20 0a 00 00 00  65 00 00 00 50 00 00 00  |map ....e...P...|
00000010  11 00 00 11 00 00 11 00  00 11 00 00 11 00 00 11  |................|
```

Now, reading this file (`Tile'Read (...)` ) produces flipped results:

```
# ada reads:
Tilenum= 17 XFlipped=FALSE YFlipped=FALSE Rotation= 1 TriFlipped=FALSE Padding= 0 Height= 17
Tilenum= 0  XFlipped=FALSE YFlipped=TRUE  Rotation= 0 TriFlipped=FALSE Padding= 1 Height= 0
Tilenum= 0  XFlipped=TRUE  YFlipped=FALSE Rotation= 0 TriFlipped=TRUE  Padding= 0 Height= 0
Tilenum= 17 XFlipped=FALSE YFlipped=FALSE Rotation= 1 TriFlipped=FALSE Padding= 0 Height= 17
# same as above, in numerical form:
0x11 [b:0001 0000] 0x11
0x00 [b:0100 0001] 0x00
0x00 [b:1000 1000] 0x00
0x11 [b:0001 0000] 0x11
```

While I would expect the result to be:

```
0x11 0 0
0x11 0 0
0x11 0 0
...
```

I am not sure to understand why `0x11` gets split into 2 nibbles (`[0001 0001]`) which are being read in two different times. (I would expect bytes to be simply flipped but being kept as a whole).

I deduce I am doing something terribly wrong.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what `0x11` and `0x00` mean. When asking Ada questions, please use Ada notation and terminology.

According to [ARM 13.13.2(9/3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-13-13-2.html), "For composite types, the Write or Read attribute for each component is called in canonical order, which is ... positional aggregate order for a record." In other words, doing

```
T : Tile;
...
Tile'Read (F, T);
```

is equivalent to

```
declare
   F1 : Tilenum_T;
begin
   Tilenum_T'Read (F, F1);
   T.Tilenum := F1;
end;

declare
   F2 : Boolean;
begin
   Boolean'Read (F, F2);
   T.Xflipped := F2;
end;
```

and so on. Each of these calls to `Read` reads at least one *stream element* (usually a byte), so `Tile'Read` reads 7 bytes.

It may be possible to redefine `Tile'Read` so it works. Much simpler and more likely to succeed is defining

```
type Tile_As_Bytes is array (1 .. 3) of U8 with Size => 24;
```

reading 3 bytes into an object of `Tile_As_Bytes`, and using `Ada.Unchecked_Conversion` to convert it to a `Tile`.

Comment: Why do you consider the Unchecked_Conversion method "more likely to succeed", Jeffrey? I see it as decreasing portability, because it is sometimes difficult to ensure that the in-memory representation of a record type exactly matches the stream representation, especially across platforms of different endianness and different scalar widths.

Comment: The endianness problem is (supposed to be) solved by the `Bit_Order` attribute (`Scalar_Storage_Order` still leaves me baffled). That aside, this fully specified record type is exactly how we are supposed to deal with objects at interfaces, be it streamed data or hardware.

Comment: The GNAT implementation of non-default Bit_Order does not work for record types with components that are themselves records (sub-records) with representation clauses and sizes that are not a "natural" scalar size for the platform, for example 5 bits. This is because GNAT maps the sub-record bit positions into default bit-order positions within a larger container of some natural size, for example 8 bits, and then refuses to pack the sub-records into 5-bit parts of the whole record type, because the sub-record component positions now refer to an 8-bit piece of storage.

Comment: Moreover, when the components of an object are larger than a Stream_Element, Bit_Order is insufficient to handle differences in byte endianness, and one then needs something like Scalar_Storage_Order, but there is nothing in the Ada standard at that level. So I do not agree that record representation clauses and Unchecked_Conversion are the right way to handle streamed data, at least if portability is needed. Proper read/write operations are better, IMO.

Comment: For this record as specified, using `Unchecked_Conversion` is simple and portable (all of the Size clauses are confirming, and I suspect that is true of the Bit_Order as well). For a more complex record, bit shifting and masking may be necessary, but that is a complication better ignored unless it becomes needed.

Answer (score 2):

Ada Streams read and write data in units of Ada.Streams.Stream_Element, which is typically 8 bits. Streams do not read or write bit by bit, even if the type being read or written needs less than 8 bits of storage.

The representation clause for type Tile defines its lay-out in memory, but not how it is represented in a stream. The stream representation is defined by the 'Read and 'Write operations for type Tile. The code you show uses the default (compiler-generated) Tile'Read which will apply, in sequence, the default (compiler-generated) Read operations for each component, and each of those will read at least one Stream_Element from the stream. Thus Tile'Read will read at least 7 Stream_Elements from the stream, not just 24 bits.

If you want to represent Tile values in the stream more compactly, as in the memory representation, you must write your own Tile'Read operation. Assuming that Stream_Element is 8 bits, that operation will read three Stream_Elements and convert those 24 bits into a Tile. This can be done in various ways, some of them using an Unchecked_Conversion. However, I would do it as follows:

```
procedure Read_Tile (
   Stream : not null access Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type'Class;
   Item   : out Tile)
is
   K : U8;
   -- The second octet in the stream.
begin
   Tilenum_t'Read (Stream, Item.Tilenum);  -- First octet.
   U8'Read (Stream, K);                    -- Second octet.
   U8'Read (Stream, Item.Height);          -- Third octet.
   -- Move the proper bits of the second octet into Item components:
   Item.XFlipped := ... extract a bit from K ...;
      ...
   Item.Padding := 0; -- I assume.
end Read_Tile;
```

You can then call Read_Tile instead of Tile'Read, or specify that Read_Tile should be used for Tile'Read, in place of the default Tile'Read.

By the way, the (GNAT-specific, non-standard) specification of Tile'Scalar_Storage_Order seems unnecessary here, because the scalar components of the Tile type are all at most one octet in size so Scalar_Storage_Order has no effect, AIUI. Why do you have it?

Comment: I had added `Scalar_Storage_Order` as a spell in order to fix my problems :) (It didn't work)